# SSRS error NUMBERORA-00932 expected CHAR got NUMBER and Memory corrupted while trying to display all when parameter is null

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I know there are existing questions regarding to this error. but my situation looks different!

I'm creating a SSRS2012 report that can manually input UserIDs number (such as 15, 130, etc..) as the IC_ID. I want to ensure when input is null, report can display all IC_ID. I tried two method to approach it.

**Data source:** Oracle Sql Developer, table:IC, **column: IC_ID datatype:NUMBER**

**Parameter:** UserIDs, datatype: Integer, allow null value.

**------------Method 1:---------------**

**SSRS dataset query, I've tried:**

```
select * from IC
where IC_ID=to_number(COALESCE(:UserIDs, IC_ID))

select * from IC
where IC_ID=to_char(COALESCE(:UserIDs, IC_ID))

select * from IC
where IC_ID=COALESCE(:UserIDs, IC_ID)
```

**But all failed with same error: NUMBERORA-00932 expected CHAR got NUMBER. When I run them in Oracle database, show same error as above. So I guess the problem is how to make data type consistent, column IC_ID data type is NUMBER, if I set parameter UserIDs as Integer, why still not consistent?**

PS:when I only use query as:

```
**select * from IC where IC_ID=(:UserIDs)**
```

no matter I set parameter datatype to text or integer, the report works fine and display info of whatever IC_ID value I manually input. But it didn't show data when parameter is null!

**---------Method 2---------**

**SSRS dataset query, I've tried:**

```
select * from IC
where IC_ID=(:UserIDs) or (:UserIDs) IS NULL
```

**failed with error: attempted to read or write protected memory. this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.** When I run this query in Oracle, it run well with not error, no matter I pass a number or null to (:UserIDs). **So I guess the problem is how to use (:UserIDs) *TWICE* in SSRS dataset query.**

I'm very sure it's not because of memory limit, because this report run well displaying all IC_ID info when there is no parameter at all. **It seems it doesn't allow one parameter to show up more than once in dataset query, whenever I tried something like: select * from IC where IC_ID=(:UserIDs) AND IC_SubID=(:UserIDs), it will fail with memory corrupt error.
But it works fine if (:UserIDs) only show up once in query.**

**---------Method 3----------------**

Some posts said in order to display all info when parameter is null, we can add a list of all IC_ID as the default value of parameter. I don't think it works for this case, because my dataset query is actually very complex, starting with a long cte. It will be too complex and slow to add this whole cte query into the list as default value.

**I would appreciate if anyone could give some help of how to solve any of above errors, or tell me other ways to display all info while parameter is null!**

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried just executing this query in the oracle database. The error isn't due to SSRS, it's an oracle error. I would debug in something like toad first, before continuing in SSRS

Comment: Thanks for your answer. in oracle, these queries : select * from IC
where IC_ID=to_number(COALESCE(:UserIDs, IC_ID))

select * from IC
where IC_ID=to_char(COALESCE(:UserIDs, IC_ID))

select * from IC
where IC_ID=COALESCE(:UserIDs, IC_ID)  show same error as in ssrs: inconsistent data types, expected CHAR got NUMBER.

Comment: But this query: select * from IC
where IC_ID=(:UserIDs) or (:UserIDs) IS NULL   run well in Oracle, without showing error, no matter I input null or a number to the parameter.  So I think if I go with method 1, the data type is a problem; if I go with method 2, how to use (:UserIDs) twice in ssrs dataset query is a problem!   Thanks for advice again,

Answer (score 0):

Isn't possible to cast the parameter as an integer? Like cast((:UserIDs as int)) (or maybe cast as a char). Don't know if this helps but i would expect that the datatype is always the same.

Or you could maybe use

```
(:UserIDs) in (case when (:UserIDs) is null then (select UserIDs from table) else (:UserIDs) end)
```

Comment: either set parameter data type Integer or Text, show same error:NUMBERORA-00932 expected CHAR got NUMBER;                  and whenever I try to use parameter more than once in the query,  it show error:attempted to read or write protected memory. this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. So I don't think your query will work. But thanks for your answer too.